# How to use looking glass (or hardware display port) with SRIOV

Tags: libvirt

I have Libvirt VM (qemu/kvm) (running windows 11) with 2 Display adapters. One is the default qxl. The second is SRIOV Using Intel UHD 770. The intel graphic drive is installed and working. The only issue is that I do not know how to use this display adapter for video acceleration. Does anyone have a reference article on how to Use one of the intel ports on the computer with this adapter. Alternatively how I can use looking glass with this adapter.